# What are the 3 methods of declaring a pointer as a parameter in a function declaration?

Tags: c

I have found and understoof this method:

```
void PrintString(char *String_Ptr)
{
    //Print String
}
```

I cannot find any other method to declare a pointer as a parameter in a function declaration.

I am led to believe there are other methods to do the same from a homework question.

Comment: I'm guessing the trick is `const`.

Comment: @theIrishUser: The tag being deprecated doesn't make it OK to write poor questions. Put some effort into your post. Explain why you believe there are other ways, what you've tried yourself, where you're stuck, etc. Be specific about your problem.

Comment: @theIrishUser, Yeah, most homework questions are now classified as too localized. If you're having trouble and whittle it down to a specific element, it can sometimes turn into a proper, reusable question. For reference, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: @KerrekSB I really believed I put the maximal effort into my post.

Comment: (The tag was deprecated precisely *because* we deemed that whether a question is for homework or not should not make any difference to the effort you should make when presenting the question.)

Comment: I have a question which tells me there are 3 syntaxes to declare a pointer in a function declaration's parameter list. 

I have been searching for the answer and cannot find it.
I provided the method that I have found and understood, I prepared the post with the correct formatting and I ask the question what are the 2 remaining ways of declaring a pointer as a parameter to a function. I tried to use the clearest english possible. 

Please edit my question If you think it can be improved further.

Comment: Please KerrkSB, I feel you are somehow sour toward me. I just need a straight answer. I have edited the post, hopefully it can be understood easily now, and will become a succesful question

Comment: There's nothing really wrong with your question, theIrishUser; it's well-formed and easily understood. But many people feel queasy providing raw answers to homework questions. If feels like we're enabling cheating, or that we'd be working with a developer in a few years who had received an inadequate education. I think you'd get a better reception here if you took a shot. Have any guesses at the answer? Does Chris' hint ring any bells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities other than mentioned in the question.

The following is exactly equivalent to the version in the question, despite the deceptive syntax suggesting that `String_Ptr` is an array. It's not, it's a pointer:

```
void PrintString(char String_Ptr[])
{
    printf("%s\n", String_Ptr);
}
```

If you know the length of the array of characters (say, 10 chars) that you want to pass to `PrintString()`, you can also pass a pointer to such an array:

```
void PrintArray10(char (*Array_Ptr)[10])
{
    printf("%s\n", *Array_Ptr); // assuming the array is '\0'-terminated
}

int main(void)
{
    char a[10] = "Blah!";
    PrintString(a); // first 2 methods
    PrintArray10(&a); // 3rd method
    return 0;
}
```

You can also camouflage the pointer with `typedef`:

```
typedef char* pchar;

void PrintString(pchar String_Ptr)
{
    printf("%s\n", String_Ptr);
}

typedef char (*pchararr10)[10];

void PrintArray10(pchararr10 Array_Ptr)
{
    printf("%s\n", *Array_Ptr); // assuming the array is '\0'-terminated
}
```

Comment: The argument of `PrintArray10` is just the same form as the one in the original question (`T*` with `T = char[10]`), so that's only *one* alternative so far...

Comment: I'd like to mention that while this is associated with my college work, it is not homework. I was not asked to do this question, I am trying to develop my understanding pointers & functions. Thanks for the help

Comment: @KerrekSB the types of the argument are different in `PrintArray10()` and in `PrintString()`. `char(*)[10]` is not the same as `char*`. The two are dereferenced differently and pointer arithmetic on the two is different. Adding 1 to them will produce not only different pointer types, but also different pointer values.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Yes yes, but they  have the same *form*. Otherwise I could just post `char *`, `int *`, `double *` and call it an answer!

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't know what form you are talking about. Internally (in the compiled code), there may be no difference between `PrintString()` and `PrintArray10()` and between the invocations of the two with `a` and `&a` respectively. This I can agree with.

Comment: The OP asks for "three different methods of declaring a pointer". Surely the answer can't just be `int *`, `char *` and `Foo *`, can it? Your second piece of code is no different from the OP's own example in that regard (only the type is different: `typedef char Foo[10];`).